# How to hide/show grid cells on hover in a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I have a two 3x3 image grids: one is black and white, and the other is colored. I want the black and white grid to show by default then when the user hovers over each cell in the grid, I want the image to be replaced by its colored version.

The issue is that I can't get the two grids in exactly the same spot. Here's my HTML layout for the first three cells:

```css
.cell_static:hover #cell_hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.cell_static #cell_hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="#" alt="1 B/W">
          </img>
        </a>
        <div id="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="1 Colored">
            </img>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="#" alt="2 B/W">
          </img>
        </a>
        <div id="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="2 Colored">
            </img>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="#" alt="3 B/W">
          </img>
        </a>
        <div id="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="3 Colored">
            </img>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is that on hover, the colored pictures appear directly under the black and white pictures instead of replacing them or appearing directly on top.

How do I repair my CSS or restructure my divs to achieve the effect that I want?

Comment: It's not the answer to your question, but you have duplicated id's in your html which is not allowed. Also it's not recommended to use `table` elements for layout purposes. Tables are used for tabular data. You can use `div` elements for layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When positioning something absolute, it is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor, which has not been set.  Below I have added top and left to the absolute element to position it in the place you want and also added relative to the static cell.

On a separate note, you may also want to remove your table - they should not be used for layout, only for tabular data, and this doesn't look like tabular data.  The only exception being if this is an email template

Also image is self closing and does not need an end tag

```css
.cell_static:hover #cell_hover {
  display: block;
}


/* add this */
.cell_static {
  position: relative;
}

.cell_static #cell_hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* add these */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:1; /* may need this to make sure it is over the other image */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="1 B/W">
        </a>
        <div id="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="1 Colored">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="2 B/W">
        </a>
        <div id="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="2 Colored">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="3 B/W">
        </a>
        <div id="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="3 Colored">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try playing with parent (container) element css and adding two different child, one that is visible in normal state of container and the other visible on hover state

**CSS:**

```
td .cell_static, td:hover .cell_hover {
  display: block;
}

td .cell_hover, td:hover .cell_static{
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="#" alt="1 B/W">
          </img>
        </a>
      </div>
        <div class="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="1 Colored">
            </img>
          </a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="#" alt="2 B/W">
          </img>
        </a>
      </div>
        <div class="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="2 Colored">
            </img>
          </a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell_static">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="#" alt="3 B/W">
          </img>
        </a>
      </div>
        <div class="cell_hover">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="3 Colored">
            </img>
          </a>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4fLwtba/)